# VBA HasNextCell function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have tried searching for a solution but cant find it.

I have a list of products, and each product has many parts. Is there a HasNext function in VBA to see if there are more parts for a product? For instance, for chicken burger, I want to pick out all the parts, put them in an array and display it in another sheet.

I cant hard-code the array, because the client would add in more products in the future. There might be 15, 20, 23 parts etc. Is there a HasNext function to get the value in the next column and add it into the array?

```
Product        | Part 1 | Part 2 | Part 3
Chicken Burger | Veggie | Bun    | Patty
```

Comment: You can still post a link to your image.

Comment: Oh sorry! Didnt know that. But the example shld suffice >.<

Comment: Why not use a do...while loop in VBA?
Simply loop until you reach a non-part Column and then abort.

Comment: Hi, but could I ask how do I abort the operation once I reach a non-part column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Range.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214585%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property to detect how "long" the title row is:

```vb
Dim col
col=Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
For i = 1 to col
    If Cells(1, col).Value <> "" Then
    '...
End
```

P.S. I wonder why MSDN refers to it as "property" instead of "method"...

Comment: Hello, is it possible for you to explain what does "col=Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column" mean? Is it the array size or ???

And also, "Cells(1, col)" ???

Comment: @MysteryR You can check out the MSDN document I linked in my answer for the meaning of [`Range.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214585%28v=office.11%29.aspx); For `Cells`, check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174290(v=office.11).aspx).